# Specify non-default bucket to enable Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a situation where I'm trying to enable Firebase Storage but also have an App Engine deployment which already created the buckets {project_name}.appspot.com and it give me the following error message:

[image: Storage Error Message]

I'm aware you can change the Firebase bucket after enabling Firebase Storage from the Firebase console, however I don't see a way to do it before/while enabling Firebase Storage.

I'm working with a few restrictions and want to see if I can enable Firebase storage with those. My first restriction is that I cannot create a separate GCP project for this. We have billing credits which are linked to the project. Another is that I cannot change the App Engine configuration, or rather doing so will only be done in the worst case since that's already being used for a production workload. Lastly, our parent organization is pretty strict in terms of their Org policies and is likely not willing to change it.

Is there a way specify a different bucket to enable Firebase Storage to avoid the conflict?

Answer (score 1):

I created a GCP project with an App Engine app and a Firebase project with Firebase Storage enabled. According to the documentation these services require a [default resource location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#default-cloud-location) in order to be initially provisioned. Firebase Storage makes use of the same default bucket as App Engine to [initialize](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#create-default-bucket). It appears that your organization might have blocked access to this bucket, which makes Firebase Storage not to work initially. You should request the [organizational policies](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/org-policy-constraints) to be temporarily allowed while Firebase Storage is provisioned, and then, as you mentioned, you can change the bucket used by Firebase Storage to a different one. Firebase makes use also of the following Storage [service account](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts):

[image: firebaseServiceAccount]

You should make sure that this account has permissions to perform its operation at creation time of the bucket, from the FAQ it also explains this is [needed](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/index#cloud-storage):

> Cloud Storage for Firebase creates a default bucket in the App Engine free tier.